# get equivalent boldness given by /section command

Tags: bold

How to obtain a comparable font "**boldness**"  resulting from **\section** command with normal text formatting ones in the following text paragraph ?
If I'm not mistaken the **\textbf** seems to produce a ***lighter bold*** effect than the one from the \section command.

Edit n.01: it render with pdflatex edited with overleaf, the font seems really the same to me 
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% 
% PREAMBULE% 
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% 
\documentclass[10pt]{article} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[italian]{babel} 
\usepackage{comment} 
\usepackage{lipsum} 
\usepackage{array} 
\usepackage{setspace} 
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor} 
\usepackage{hyperref} 
\usepackage{pbox} 
\usepackage{longtable} 
\usepackage{enumitem} %help to customize itemize and enumerate spcaces ans spreads 
\usepackage{makecell} 
\usepackage[a4paper, left=2cm, right=2cm, top=2cm, bottom=2cm, includeheadfoot]{geometry} 
% \usepackage{parskip} 
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\graphicspath{ {./pix/} } 
\usepackage{wrapfig} 



%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% 
% Set Helvetica Font in Text and Math in LaTeX % 
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% 
\usepackage[scaled=0.92]{helvet} 
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage[helvet]{sfmath} 
\everymath={\sf}

Comment: The bold only appears darker because the section heading is in a larger size in most document classes.

Comment: the latex format doesn't define `\section`  it is defined by the document class in use, about which you have given no information, but most fonts are only set up at two weights so `\textbf` but the heading may be a larger size, or a different font family, impossible to guess.

Comment: I understood my mistake:
\section*{book} is equivalent to {\Large \textbf {book}} and not to \Large{\textfb{book}}